How can I customise the error messages in JSON Forms
I am using React and JSON Forms to build a form with an input that has a minimum length restriction and an email format. I am unable to generate a custom error message.

The docs say to use ajv-errors, but I haven't been able to change the error message that appears.
Schema:
export const schema = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    inputControl: {
      type: 'string',
      format: 'email',
      minLength: 7,
    },
  },
}

UI Schema:
export const uischema = {
  type: 'VerticalLayout',
  elements: [
    {
      type: 'Control',
      scope: '#/properties/inputControl',
      label: 'Please enter your email address',
    },
  ],
}


I have tried using ajv-errors. I cannot remember exactly what, but nothing worked. i.e. the error message on the screen remains the same.
When I tried adding a keyword from examples on the internet, the linter always tells me that one of the keys is missing or gives some other error.


To define a custom error message using the errorMessage keyword in your schemas, you should wrap the Ajv instance with ajvErrors instance.
(note that since you are using format: "email" I'd assume you are also using the ajv-fromats package)
import Ajv from "ajv";
import ajvErrors from "ajv-errors";
import ajvFormats from "ajv-formats";

// allErrors must be true when using ajvErrors package
const ajv = ajvFormats(ajvErrors(new Ajv({ allErrors: true })));

export const schema = {
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    inputControl: {
      type: "string",
      format: "email",
      minLength: 7,
      errorMessage: "Email is required and must be at least 7 characters long", // or what ever custom message you want to add
    },
  },
};

...

